# Use same ss-id cookie across all subdomains - ServiceStack

Tags: cookies, servicestack

In my Auth API set the ss-id cookie domain to be used for all subdomains like so in my AppHost.Configure method:

```
 Config = new HostConfig
 {
     RestrictAllCookiesToDomain = ".mywebsite.com"
 };
```

My browser will include this cookie in every request to every every subdomain API of mine, for example: `user.mywebsite.com`.

Unfortunately, my APIs are responding with `SET COOKIE` responses, intermittently!

So sometimes I get what I do not want with my `ss-id` Cookie:

[image]

And sometimes, logging in and out, clearing my cookies for `mywebsite.com` I can get what I want and my APIs are sharing the same cookie:

[image]

I have attempted to add:

```
 Config = new HostConfig
 {
     RestrictAllCookiesToDomain = ".mywebsite.com"
 };
```

To other APIs' AppHost.Configure but this does not seem to remedy the situation, nor does it seem necessary because the `ss-id` cookie set by my auth API successful login response is for all subdomains (.mywebsite.com)

I am suspecting that Ajax requests are being sent to APIs without the `ss-id` cookie have been set yet, a timing issue across multiple Ajax requests and the login process.

Is my logic correct? Since the `ss-id` SET COOKIE domain in the response header for the initial response is `.mywebsite.com` after login that none of my other APIs will respond with a new SET COOKIE for `ss-id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re not going to know what’s happening unless you view the raw HTTP Headers to see what’s actually happening.

It’s possible there’s a race condition with multiple Ajax requests which we’re initially sent without ss-id cookies in which case they can have different ss-id cookies returned in which case the last Set-Cookie instruction will win and be used going forward provided they all use the same `/` path.